# Small display issue on company page with Founded part

Tags: bug, jobs, design

The Founded part (here *Gegründet 1979*) is partly behind the gray area that contains the description of the company. [See profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/trimble-navigation?c=mfDqDWDVTmIEkEFi) for reference.

The issue remains when I switch to an other language. I´m using latest Chrome and Zoom is set to 100%.

[image]